# Is there a way to check if a delegate is a value or a reference type?

Tags: swift, value-type, reference-type

Lets say we had something like this:

```
protocol Delegate {}

struct Value: Delegate {}
class Reference: Delegate {}

struct Test {
    let delegate: Delegate
}
```

How could we know if a delegate is a struct (value type) or a class (reference type)?

First thought that comes to mind is to check memory address equality after making a copy of a delegate:

```
struct Test {
    let delegate: Delegate

    var isReferenceType: Bool {
        let copy = delegate

        let copyAddress = // ... get memory address of a copy
        let originalAddress = // ... get memory address of an original

        return copyAddress == originalAddress
    }
}
```

---

1. Is it even possible to do this?
2. Is there more elegant/correct way of doing this?
3. Copying a value type might potentially be an expensive operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every class conforms to the `AnyClass` protocol. However enums and structs won't. Utilising that you can check if it's a class or a struct(or even an enum)

```
struct Test {
    let delegate: Delegate

    var isReferenceType: Bool {
        return type(of:delegate) is AnyClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot of such a simple solution... Stupid me.

Comment: Happens to me all the time(mostly when I forgot to drink my morning coffee)